# Force dependencies to import from a separate location (AWS Lambda)

Tags: python, import, aws-lambda, dependencies, python-import

I am working with an AWS Lambda function and have several dependencies.

As an example to simplify things, I will use requests (and yes, I know requests is available from Botocore, but I have other dependencies that aren't).
my project structure is as follows:

```
lambda_function/
    lambda_function.py
    misc/
        __init__.py
        example.py
    packages/
        requests/
        urllib3/
        ...
```

The packages/ directory was obtained by doing
`pip install requests --target ./packages`

in lambda_function.py we have

```
from misc.example import foo
```

In example.py we have

```
from packages import requests
def foo():
    return requests.get('example.com')
```

which gives a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3', even though urllib3 is definitely inside packages/
I know this can be avoided by just putting everything in one top level directory, but there are quite a few dependencies and I want to keep everything clean. Is there a way to force requests to import from the packages/ directory instead, or someway to add packages/ to the path?
I have already tried doing

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('lambda_function/packages'))
```

but to no avail.

Comment: I think the right way to handle it is layers ... it was a pain to setup when i did it... but now that i have my layers setup its a breeze

Comment: what do you mean by layers?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solutions would be:

1. Just copy packages to inside of your lambda app, like this:

   ```
   - rm -rf ./lambda
   - mkdir -p ./lambda
   - pip install --upgrade pip
   - pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirement.txt -t lambda
   - cp -rf <application_code> lambda/
   ```

   In effect, your code would be structured like that:

   ```
   lambda_function/
       lambda_function.py
       misc/
           __init__.py
           example.py
       requests/
       urllib3/
       ...
   ```

   Not elegant and has the potential for harm.
2. Following solution:

   ```
   sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('lambda_function/packages'))
   ```

   Had no chance of working because if you simply run python and print sys.path you will see a bunch of paths and then you were appending yours at the end. When you import a package, python scans the path from the first to the last and the first that matches will be used (this is roughly speaking how virtualenvs are working). In your case, the name was matching what lambda has as a stdlib, solution in the normal world would be to do:

   ```
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('lambda_function/packages'))
   ```

   Would that work with lambda? My guess is it would, but have to be done first thing before imports are performed, which in itself sometimes is tricky.
3. Modify either PATH or PYTHONPATH of your lambda runtime

   Snippet for terraform:

   ```
   environment {
     variables = {
       ENV            = "${terraform.workspace}"
       PYTHONPATH     = "packages",
     }
   }
   ```

   In my env, the task is located within /var/task, and the above line will add /var/task/packages to sys.path.